# call JQuery ajax at intervals doesn't redirect page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php script that checks that a session value matches a db value, if not the user is logged out and taken to the home page.  At the moment this works fine when the script is triggered by opening each page (it is added as an include) but I am trying to call it using jQuery setInterval function with ajax

The jQuery

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"includes/multi_check.php"
    }); 
}, 5000); //5 seconds
```

The php

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userID = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$db_token = $row['session_token'];
$taken = $row['taken_over'];

if($_SESSION['session'] != $db_token){
    $_SESSION['taken_over_by'] = $taken;
    header("location:http://www.x-rayqa.co.uk/index.php");
}
```

When monitoring the call in the console the call is working and if I echo a value within the if argument the correct value is displayed when the condition is true but I am unable to make the page redirect.  It completely ignores the header redirect.

Also, with the jQuery function running the sessions aren't passed to the home page when the user is redirected when using the manually triggered method, as soon as I comment out the jQuery method the manual method works as expected

Comment: can you check what is returned from your ajax call?  maybe put a 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
in your ajax call... make sure everything is coming back from your php page just fine

Comment: Maybe cached jQuery responses? Check your network traffic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is being executed in the background, but what happens in the background doesn't affect the actual application.  If you want to affect the client, you need ajax to send data to the client, and then have the client's browser react appropriately.  Something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"includes/multi_check.php",
        success:function(d){
            if(d=="0"){
                window.location="http://www.x-rayqa.co.uk/index.php";
            }
        }
    }); 
}, 5000); //5 seconds
```

And then in your PHP file, do something like this:

```
if($_SESSION['session'] != $db_token){
    $_SESSION['taken_over_by'] = $taken;
    exit("0");
}
exit("1");
```

So basically all this will do is either send the number `1` or `0` back to the user via ajax and if the user gets a `0`, they will be redirected to the home page.  This may or may not work, but this is the idea that you need to follow to get AJAX to work properly.